# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined using event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having some troubles passing values from a child component to the parent `state`.  The error being given is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` upon entering a value in an `input`

```
interface InterfaceState {
  password: string;
}

class Parent extends Component<InterfaceState> {
  private static INITIAL_STATE = {
    password: ''
  };

  private static propKey(propertyName: string, value: any): object {
    return { [propertyName]: value };
  }

  public constructor(props: InterfaceProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...Parent.INITIAL_STATE };
  }

  public render() {
    const { password } = this.state;
    return (
     <Child setStateWithEvent={setStateWithEvent} password={password}/>;
    );
  }
  private setStateWithEvent(event: any, columnType: string): void {
    this.setState(
      Parent.propKey(columnType, (event.target as any).value)
    );
  }
}
```

and the child component is

```
const Child = ({
  password,
  setStateWithEvent
}: InterfaceProps) => {

  return (
     <input
         name="password"
         value={password}
         onChange={(event: any) => setStateWithEvent(event, 'password')}
         type="password"
         placeholder="Password"
     />
  );
};
```

How can I pass `state` from the child to the parent using `setStateWithEvent`?

Comment: Try binding `setStateWithEvent` in the `Parent` constructor: `this.setStateWithEvent = this.setStateWithEvent.bind(this);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind your `setStateWithEvent` function in `Parent`.

Add this to your constructor :

```
this.setStateWithEvent = this.setStateWithEvent.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arrow functions as below:

```
private setStateWithEvent = (event: any, columnType: string) => {
    this.setState(
      Parent.propKey(columnType, (event.target as any).value)
    );
  }
```

refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more details.